# Print the Immediate Left Character of the Text Searched in a Text File Using Python

Tags: python, regex, replace, find

As I am running a program where I want to replace the searched text with my replacement text. However, at the first instance it does the great work but on running the next instance it is not generating the required output.

```
search_text = "something"
replacement_text = "\""+search_text+"\""
```

First Run:

```
Input : something
Output : "something"
```

Second Run:

```
Input: something
Output: ""something""
```

Required Output on second run: `not found`

So, I want to print an error that the exact match cannot be found or I want to find out the immediate left character of the searched word in the text file.

Code goes like this:

```py
texterror = ["a","b","c","d"]

def dothereplace(search_text, replace_text):
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        data = file.read()
        data = data.replace(search_text, replace_text)
    with open(filepath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(data)

search_text = ""
replace_text = ""
for i in range(0,len(texterror)):
    search_text = texterror[i]
    replace_text = "\""+search_text+"\""
    dothereplace(search_text,replace_text)
    print(texterror[i],"replacement done")
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot and better understand the issues you are having. Remember to add any specific information or errors involving your attempt. To learn more about how the [SO] community can help you, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird, why would the second run be `not found`? Clearly `something` is in `"something"`.

If for some reason you want to replace a word with "word" only once, then you have to code your own replace method to specifically ignore search_text surrounded by quotes instead of using data.replace()

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by searching for the replaced_text at the beginning itself through a function call

```py
def search_in_file(replace_text):
    with open(filepath,"r",encoding="utf-8") as file:
       data_show = file.readlines()
       for row in data_show:
           word = replace_text
       return row.find(word)
# if search_in_file returns -1,replace text not available and do the replacement
# if it's 0 then no replacement replacement already dond
```